# New users should be informed to use @ when replying

Tags: feature-request, comment, notifications, comment-replies

It's getting silly how many times I notice people not using @ when replying to someone. This is very concerning since the one who replies never gets an answer.

It should be written somewhere near the reply text box that @ is required if you wish to reply.

Comment: But it is not always required. Sometimes it is even automatically stripped.

Comment: @Integrator thank you, I am well aware of this. My point was that it is *not always* necessary to write an `@user` for example in the case you mention. But there is also a slightly more subtle case, namely a postowner replying to the unique commenter on their post does not need to notify either. Or, as common generalization, as long as there are only two users (including the owner) involved in conversation on a post it is not necessary to use notification. And, then a notification might even be autodeleted on submission. Thus the problem might (or not) be less widespread than it appears.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Already exists.  This is what users below 100 reputation see when leaving a comment:

[image: comment]

Comment: It took me ages to start using @. I did notice people using it, but I thought it was just way people chose to address each other without necessarily having any sort of notification associated with it. I missed both the paragraph above and the notifications on the inbox. Having said this, I suppose the problem here is me, I'm not a very visual person.

Comment: I have a habit of typing a space after the @ symbol. Hence I don't get a match. It would be nice if that was a common enough problem that it might be addressed.